# sending escape-sequence to serial port with c#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

How can I send simple Escape-Sequences to a serial-port (COM4 in my case) with C# in Windows XP and Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a form the easy way is to drop the SerialPort control on to it and set PortName to COM4.

If you don't use a form you can declare the control from System.IO.Ports.

Then set baud rate, parity etc. to match the port on the other end.

Here is a complete example on how to use it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx